# Concatenate/append bitcoin address to image_tag source Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, string-concatenation

I have a hash that contains a bitcoin address.
The hash looks like this:

```
{"status"=>"success", "data"=>{"user_id"=>2, "address"=>"2NE9LK7LGKr9dStvxpF64ucKyoywnfcLd1W", "label"=>"slesle91", "available_balance"=>"0.00000000", "pending_received_balance"=>"0.00000000"}}
```

I can display the bitcoin address via:

```
<%= @address["data"]["address"] %>
```

How can I add this to an image_tag to get a url like this that create a qr code:

```
<%= image_tag src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl="2NE9LK7LGKr9dStvxpF64ucKyoywnfcLd1W" %>
```

So I am looking for a solution to do something similar to:

```
%= image_tag src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl="<%= @address["data"]["address"] %>" %>
```

Any comment or assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this in the following manner:

```
<%= image_tag src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=250x250&cht=qr&chl=#{@balance["data"]["address"]}" %>
```